# Probability of putting ball into bucket

Tags: probability

I have 5 identical balls and I have three buckets which are
labelled A, B, C.
(I perform the following experiment. For each ball I pick one of
the three buckets with equal probability and put the ball in that bucket. I
claim that the probability that each bucket has at least one ball is 50/81. One
might think this probability would be given by your answer to (b) divided
by your answer to (a), which should work out to 2/7.
(c) Explain why your answer to (b) divided by your answer to (a) is not the
correct probability.
 Derive my answer.

Ans :

The portion where i need help is the second portion, where the experiment is performed.
Can anyone help with this?

Comment: What attempts have you made so far?

Comment: @Patrick  I have edited the question to include my attempts..

Answer (score 0):

For $(a)$ you are under counting by a lot.  Since the buckets are labeled and thus *distinguishable* then putting all $5$ balls into just one bucket accounts for $3$ ways and not just $1$ (i.e. all in $A$, all in $B$ or all in bucket $C$ = $3$ *different* ways).  In other words, these would be partitions if the bucket's were NOT labeled.

Let's solve $(b)$ before solving $(a)$:

Imagine the five balls lined up alongside each other like this

$$ * \ \ \ * \ \ \ * \ \ \ * \ \ \ * $$  Now let's place vertical bars between these balls to represent placing them into the separate buckets.  We will say that all of the balls to the left of the first bar are in bucket $A$, the balls between the first and second bar are in bucket $B$ and the balls to the right of the third bar reside in the final bucket.  An example is:

$$ * \ \ | \ * \ \ \ * \ \ |\ * \ \ \ * $$

We can see that there are $4$ places to place $2$ bars and so in total we have $ \binom{4}{2}$ ways to do this.

For $(a)$ solve $(b)$ with $8$ balls this time and at the end remove one ball form each bucket.  Do you see how this gives the number of ways to assign the balls with some buckets possibly containing $0$ balls?  [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) page provides a proof for the general case if you are interested.  It is easily generalized.

I'm actually stumped on $(c)$...maybe my brain will work better tomorrow.

Comment: -   I am confused. Are you talking about the 2nd portion.I think answer to 1st portion is we had undifferentiated balls, but differentiated buckets. Hence a partition 
of the balls, depending on its nature, will give a different number of arrangements. For 
example, the partition 2+2+1 gives 3 arrangements since there are 3 ways of choosing the 
bucket that gets only one ball. Acronym ( u,d) :
5 0 0 ======3
4 1 0 ======6
3 1 1 ======3
3 2 0 ======6
2 2 1 ======3

21 is the answer. 

b) For this 6.

Comment: I am confused. Are you talking about the 2nd portion.I think answer to 1st portion is we had undifferentiated balls, but differentiated buckets. Hence a partition of the balls, depending on its nature, will give a different number of arrangements. For example, the partition 2+2+1 gives 3 arrangements since there are 3 ways of choosing the bucket that gets only one ball. Acronym ( u,d) : 5 0 0 ======3 4 1 0 ======6 3 1 1 ======3 3 2 0 ======6 2 2 1 ======3 , So 21 is the answer. b) For this 6 is the answer, .... Could you please help me with the 2nd part of the question?

Comment: I got the resolution. Thanks.